# jquery async:false won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have a list of imdb ids stored in the database. What I want to do is, iterate over these and query a web service provider, for example TMDB and get the movie thumbnail associated with that imdb id.

I have fetched the data from the database, and stored it in response.

```
<script>
    var results_area = $(".results-area");
    function render(response) {
        var img_thumbnail = $(".img-thumbnail");
        var quote= $(".quote");
        results_area.empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {
            img_thumbnail.attr('src', getImageThumbnail(response.d[i].imdbId));
            quote.text("Reviews:" + response.d[i].quote);
            results_area.append(img_thumbail.clone(),quote.clone()); 
        }
    }

    function getImageThumbnail(imdbId) {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + imdbId + "?",
            data: param,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function () {
            }
        });
     }
</script>
```

Since my dataType is 'jsonp', async:false won't work. What is happening is since in my html img src="#", it stays the same after the for loop finishes.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: JSONP is always asynchronous.

Comment: In the loop you're constantly overwriting the text in `.quote` and the source of `.img-thumbnail`, what are you trying to accomplish there?

Comment: As you noted you can't use `async: false` with jsonp, but using `async: false` at any time is a very bad idea, it will lock the user's browser up (or tab in the case of Chrome) and make it unusable if any of the requests take a long time.